# Linking jquery mobile error loading page

Tags: jquery

i have a problem with jquery mobile. When i test the site on my laptop the linking, between the sites works great. But when i test it on my phone i get, this message "Error Loading Page" my code is below thanks in advance.

```
<a style="text-decoration:none; color:#AFA438; font-size:10px;"       href="justice.php">justice design group</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
<a href="multipage.html" rel="external">Multi-page link</a>
```

Or read this 
[enter link description here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.1.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)

Comment: Cant thank you enough mate! you made my day! have a nice weekend! when i can in 6 minutes i accept it!

Comment: i have to wait 1 minute to accept your answer Stack overflow's rules ;-)

Comment: Sorry can't require 15 rep  :(